# Manipulating data in R data frame

Tags: r

Here is a sample data frame and I have to add holidays volume to next working day volume:

```
> emp.data
   sno       date volume day
1    1 2016-02-21     10 Mon
2    2 2016-02-22     20 Tue
3    3 2016-02-23     30 Wed
4    4 2016-02-24     40 Thu
5    5 2016-02-25     50 Fri
6    6 2016-02-26      5 Sat
7    7 2016-02-27      8 Sun
8    8 2016-02-28     10 Mon
9    9 2016-03-01     20 Tue
10  10 2016-03-02     30 Wed
11  11 2016-03-03     40 Thu
12  12 2016-03-04     50 Fri
13  13 2016-03-05      5 Sat
14  14 2016-03-06      8 Sun
15  15 2016-03-07     10 Mon
```

Here I need to add every Sat & Sun volume to Mon volume. I am doing this by finding the row indices of Mon and adding to it (vector manipulation).

But the problem here is, if the first day starts with Sun--we need to add only Sun volume to Mon because there is no Sat. Likewise if start day is Mon and end day also Mon, the Mon vector length is more than Sat & Sun vector where recycling is happening.

Sorry for the earlier confusing post. Hope this makes the question simple.

Comment: What  do you mean by "if the first day starts with Sun"? The first day of the data frame, the first day of the month, something else?

Comment: As I told, I'm playing with vectors. In the above ex. data frame Mon vector is (1,8,15), Sat is (6,13) and Sun is (7,14)--here Mon vector length is more. if the first day starts with Sun, the vectors become Mon as (2,9,16), Sat as (7,14) and Sun as (1,8,15) which again varying length and simple vector addition is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is an approach using the `dplyr` package.

We use the `case_when` function to define the conditions that have to be met for adding the *volume* of Saturday and Sunday to the Mondays.

That is, what do when: there is no Sunday, there's no Saturday, there's both Saturday and sunday.

Results are stored in the `holiday_volume` column.

```
mutate(emp.data, 
       holiday_volume = case_when(
         is.na(lag(.$day)) & .$day == "Mon" ~ .$volume,
         is.na(lag(.$day, 2)) & .$day == "Mon" ~ .$volume + lag(.$volume),
         !is.na(lag(.$day)) & .$day == "Mon"~ .$volume + lag(.$volume) + lag(.$volume, 2)
       ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.

After doing some research and few other posts, I got this answer. (I don't know why but one answer got deleted here?? But this answer is based on that answer only after few modifications)

```
library(tidyverse)
emp.data_subset<-subset(emp.data[,c("day","volume")])
emp.data_subset$lag1<-lag(emp.data_subset$volume,1,default = 0)
emp.data_subset$lag2<-lag(emp.data_subset$volume,2,default = 0)
emp.data$volume<-ifelse(
    emp.data_subset$day=="Mon",
    emp.data_subset$volume+emp.data_subset$lag1+emp.data_subset$lag2,
    emp.data_subset$volume
  )
```

Here "emp.data_subset" for ease of doing and it looks likes this after performing two lag columns.

```
> emp.data_subset
   day volume lag1 lag2
1  Mon     10    0    0
2  Tue     20   10    0
3  Wed     30   20   10
4  Thu     40   30   20
5  Fri     50   40   30
6  Sat      5   50   40
7  Sun      8    5   50
8  Mon     10    8    5
9  Tue     20   10    8
10 Wed     30   20   10
11 Thu     40   30   20
12 Fri     50   40   30
13 Sat      5   50   40
14 Sun      8    5   50
15 Mon     10    8    5
```

Adding of "emp.data_subset" volume, lag1 & lag2 for "Mon" to "emp.data$volume" for "Mon" gives the result.

Final "emp.data" will looks like this:

```
> emp.data
   sno       date volume day
1    1 2016-02-21     10 Mon
2    2 2016-02-22     20 Tue
3    3 2016-02-21     30 Wed
4    4 2016-02-22     40 Thu
5    5 2016-02-20     50 Fri
6    6 2016-02-21      5 Sat
7    7 2016-02-22      8 Sun
8    8 2016-02-20     23 Mon
9    9 2016-02-20     20 Tue
10  10 2016-02-20     30 Wed
11  11 2016-02-21     40 Thu
12  12 2016-02-22     50 Fri
13  13 2016-02-21      5 Sat
14  14 2016-02-22      8 Sun
15  15 2016-02-20     23 Mon
```